# Java Code for getting memory heapdumps of an application for monitoring it

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm

Hi i need some java code for getting the memory dumps of JVM to monitor the application performance. Is it possible to analyse the memory dumps using java code. I need to analyse the memory dumps of several JVM's available on different interconnected networks.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was put on hold. "i need some java code for getting the memory dumps" would suggest that this is a question about a code sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by getting HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean instance (named ) and invoking dumpHeap() method:

```
MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(server,
                "com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic", HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class);
bean.dumpHeap("filename", /* live objects */ true);
```

More info can be found in [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html#dumpHeap(java.lang.String, boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html#dumpHeap%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

Another option if you need to compare memory usage is to get [MemoryPoolMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html) which can return several useful informations about various memory spaces

Comment: When i am trying to invoke the code above i am getting below error
Note - i am using JDK 1.7

"Access restriction: The type HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean is not       accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program   Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar"

Comment: I managed to run the code but this gives me same result as the below commands

cmd:> jsp
for finding the process id

cmd:> jmap -dump:format=b,file=c:\Temp\mymemorydump pid

But i need something that will allow me to read this memorydump file and compare two dumps

Comment: @nikhilgupta86 - I've extended my answer, hope it will help